# IEX: Historical market caps

Tags: stock, stockquotes, elixir-iex

I'm using the IEX api (iextrading.com) and I've found how to get the market cap for a stock (/stock/aapl/stats) and historical close prices (/stock/aapl/chart/5y) but does anyone know how to get historical market caps? I could use the shares outstanding data from the /stats endpoint and multiple by the last close price but it appears $30B different than what google says for a market cap (markets are closed today so IEX and google provide the same price).

Answer (score 0):

try to use Koyfin How to get historical market cap at Koyfin

[image: 1]